# On selected index change in Dropdownlist1 should select same value in Dropdownlist2?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have a page where there are two Dropdownlist and both have the same data in it but when user  selects the value in  Dropdownlist1  ,same value should  be selected automatically  in Dropdownlist2?

Thanks 
Smartdev

Comment: Do you want to do this on the client-side with script, or are you doing a postback when they select from the first dropdown, and you need to do it on the server?

Comment: I want to do it on the server side. 
Thanks for the reply womp.can you suggest something.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that a couple of ways. If you're using the built in asp.net postback approach then you can set the value of the dropdown box server side.

If you're wanting to do this on the front end you can use jQuery (or standard Javascript) to set the `selectedIndex` of the second dropdown.

I assume that's the kind of answer you are after and not just for someone to write the code for you. :)

Comment: thanks jamie i was just looking for which would be good way was trying to know that. im not looking for smone to write the code for me. 
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

so in your code behind OnSelectedIndexChanged, you need to rebind both DropDownList1 and DropDownList2 to the same datasource.